# Unable to edit or view code from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Unable to view the source code in android studio, while VS Code opened java/XML fine, I restarted with clear cache, UTF-8 to other, sync with file, deleted .idea and restarted but still getting this problem.

May I know is this coming from a virus or any other malware affected android studio / Windows 11...

Even I uninstalled android studio and reinstalled it today but how this coming again is my question...

The given image was my files which were unable to edit or even change a sentence may rewrite unsaved java files with this text.

[image: Error of java file in the android studio]

Answer (score 0):

I already encountered the same issue, I had tried all solutions (delete .idea dir, invalidate cache) but nothing worked.

I had finally uninstall and reinstall Android Studio, the problem had disappeared

Comment: Yes, I tried uninstalled and reinstalled, but still the issue not fixed for me... 
I installed android studio in my another partition, so I am unable to find where cache file is located for android studio. Not in C:/users/username folder.